# DBMS_LDAP.delete_s result in error: ERR_268 Cannot find a partition for

Tags: plsql, ldap, apache-directory

I have problem in deleting any LDAP entry using `DBMS_LDAP.delete_s` function. My code looks like:

```
DECLARE
    l_ldap_user    VARCHAR2(256) := 'dc=example,dc=com';
    l_session      DBMS_LDAP.session;
    ...
BEGIN
    ...
    l_retval := dbms_ldap.delete_s(l_session, l_ldap_user || ',cn=Tink');
    ...
END
/
```

I use Apache Directory Studio version 2.0.0 to store LDAP data and it looks like:

```
dn: dc=example,dc=com
objectclass: top
objectclass: domain
dc: example
userPassword:: e1NTSEF9YTZIYUF0U1BGSnFOQ2piZm9ENStpV3BMQnJ1VnBlT21IbFAraHc9P
 Q==

dn: cn=Tink,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: person
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: top
cn: Tink
sn: Tink
userPassword:: e1NTSEF9eDZBZUV2SzVEYmkrYlA2c0FCZU1zdk5YMzlUN1JUL3FOSk9KQmc9P
 Q==
```

As a result I receive following error message:

```
Error report -
ORA-31202: DBMS_LDAP: LDAP client/server error: No such object. 
NO_SUCH_OBJECT: failed for MessageType : DEL_REQUEST
Message ID : 2
    Del request
        Entry : 'dc=example,dc=com,cn=Tink'
org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.message.DeleteRequestImpl@ac23db41: 
ERR_268 Cannot find a partition for dc=example,dc=com,cn=Tink
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_ERROR", line 86
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_LDAP", line 1487
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_LDAP", line 709
ORA-06512: at line 69
31202. 00000 -  "DBMS_LDAP: LDAP client/server error: %s"
*Cause:    There is a problem either on the LDAP server or on the client.
*Action:   Please report this error to the LDAP server administrator or
           your Database administrator.
```

Help me please because I run out of ideas how repair this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in the line:

```
l_retval := dbms_ldap.delete_s(l_session, l_ldap_user || ',cn=Tink');
```

Correct reading nodes in LDAP is: leaf.domainname.domainname

Answer for this problem:

```
l_retval := dbms_ldap.delete_s(l_session, 'cn=Tink,' || l_ldap_user); --l_ldap_user = 'dn=domain,dn=com'.
```